# Single quotes splits my URls

Tags: php, quotes, double-quotes

For example, when i click url below

```
http://mysite.com/?s=Dominos' books
```

code below works

```
$param= $_GET['s'];  
$completeurl = 'http://somesite.com/?param1='.trim($param).'&key=987539873';
```

So single quote (') in `$param` splits the `$completeurl` and i want to keep ' intact.

Altought i replace single quotes (') in $completeurl with double quote (") it doesn't work. 
How can i prevent this unwanted splittings?

Comment: do u want to keep the `'` intact?

Answer (score 2):

You need to URL-encode.  `"` becomes `%22`

```
$completeurl = 'http://somesite.com/?param1=' . urlencode(trim($param)) . '...';
```

See also:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
- http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm#whatwhy

Answer (score 0):

try this line:

```
  $completeurl = 'http://somesite.com/?param1='.str_replace(array("'",' '), '', $param).'&key=987539873';
```

OR if you want to keep the `'` intact

```
$completeurl = 'http://somesite.com/?param1='.urlencode(trim($param)).'&key=987539873';
```